# Using new composer to install libraries in Yii2 Project

Tags: installation, composer-php, libraries, yii2-advanced-app

I already install Yii2 Advanced template via archive and already make a half of my application but now i want to install some library that just can be installed via composer,so i installed composer as well,but now how can i install a library for my yii2 project using that composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

from the installation guide (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) to get bower and npm package through Composer, then create a *composer.json* file, an example from a clean advanced template installation:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable" : true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then how can i check if my yii project already connected with composer?

Comment: i just know and check it but there is differences between my project and your example,in your example there is this command line
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable" : true,
but in mine just "minimum-stability": "stable",
is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i do what you told me earlier,then is it alright? and is it finish? or any step i have to do?
and which file i can check that my yii file is already connected with composer?

Comment: Hi @pandu-pratama-nur, it's ok. Try to install some package and see how it works. There's a website with very useful packages: http://demos.krajee.com/ 
Also, try to answer to the same post, not open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Composer Packages**
Many third-party libraries are released in terms of Composer packages. You can install such libraries by taking the following two simple steps:

1. modify the *composer.json* file of your application and specify which
   Composer packages you want to install.
2. Run *composer install* to install the specified packages.

**Using Downloaded Libraries**
If a library is not released as a Composer package, you should follow its installation instructions to install it. In most cases, you will need to download a release file manually and unpack it in the *BasePath/vendor* directory, where *BasePath* represents the base path of your application.

If a library carries its own class autoloader, you may install it in the entry script of your application. It is recommended the installation is done before you include the *Yii.php* file so that the Yii class autoloader can take precedence in autoloading classes.

If a library does not provide a class autoloader, but its class naming follows PSR-4, you may use the Yii class autoloader to autoload the classes. All you need to do is just to declare a root alias for each root namespace used in its classes. For example, assume you have installed a library in the directory *vendor/foo/bar*, and the library classes are under the *xyz* root namespace. You can include the following code in your application configuration:

```
    [
    'aliases' => [
        '@xyz' => '@vendor/foo/bar',
    ],
]
```

If neither of the above is the case, it is likely that the library relies on PHP include path configuration to correctly locate and include class files. Simply follow its instruction on how to configure the PHP include path.

In the worst case when the library requires explicitly including every class file, you can use the following method to include the classes on demand:

- Identify which classes the library contains.
- List the classes and the corresponding file paths in *Yii::$classMap*
  in the entry script of the application. For example,

  Yii::$classMap['Class1'] = 'path/to/Class1.php';
  Yii::$classMap['Class2'] = 'path/to/Class2.php';

More Reference info can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html